# Installing / maintaining Jenkins on a Linux host machine

Tags: linux, jenkins, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04

We are currently provisioning a physical server as our automation server. We are making considerations as far as what our native operating system should be on this physical machine.

We are going to use a Linux OS as our operating system. From the [Jenkins download page](https://jenkins.io/download/), I can see that Jenkins’ package distribution is available to Red Hat / Fedora / CentOS (which we will not be using), as well as Ubuntu / Debian. I also notice that a Generic Java package (WAR) distribution is available.

- Am I correct in assuming that if we use a non-Ubuntu / non-Debian
  operating system, we can still install Jenkins via the WAR
  distribution without issue?
- If we are not able to install via WAR without issue, are we relegated
  to using Debian / Ubuntu if we’re going to install Jenkins on a Linux
  machine (with the possibility of Red Hat / Fedora / CentOS ruled
  out)?

It should probably be noted that we will likely install / upgrade on the [Jenkins LTS release schedule](https://jenkins.io/changelog-stable/).

Thanks for any guidance from anybody who may have experience installing / maintaining a Jenkins instance on a Linux machine!

Comment: Jenkins can be installed on any web server running Java. You should therefore be able to run it on any flavour of Linux. Since it's Java based, I would recommend a lot of RAM.

Comment: Excellent suggestion! Especially the part: 'Since it's java based, I would recommend a lot of RAM'. That is extremely helpful advice as we're not provisioning this server.